# UploadedFile in $request

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to access pic in $request which is instance of UploadedFile class but when I use

```
$request->pic;
```

it returns nothing...

this is my dd($request->all()) result

```
array:4 [
"title" => "blah blah
"desc" => "some text"
"respawn" => "mail"
"pic" => UploadedFile {#27
-test: false
-originalName: "hamayesh-hesabdari2.jpg"
-mimeType: "image/jpeg"
-size: 160295
-error: 0
}
]
```

how can I access it?

Comment: you should try $request["pic"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`file()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files) method to get the file:

```
$request->file('pic')
```

And [`hasFile()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files) method to check if file exists:

```
if ($request->hasFile('pic'))
```